# how do I rewrite a URL and maintain the file name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite written in my .htaccess file. I am trying to redirect the following

`https://olddomain.com/folder/file.pdf` to `https://newdomain.com/folder/file.pdf`. `file.pdf` can change so I need to change the domain but leave the folder and file name needs to stay what ever it is. it could be `file.pdf` or `file1.pdf` etc

I have this code in my `.htaccess` file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://newdomain.com/folder/%1 [R=301,NC]
```

If the `file.pdf` exists on the old server then the redirect works but if the file does not exist on the old server the redirect does not work.

Any help fixing this would be appreciated.

Comment: What other directives do you have in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: ... and what happens exactly when the redirect does not occur? What response are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

> If the `file.pdf` exists on the old server then the redirect works but if the file does not exist on the old server the redirect does not work.

That sounds like you've put the rule/redirect in the wrong place. If you have other directives *before* this redirect that implement a front-controller pattern then you will experience this same behaviour since any request for a non-existent file would be routed to the front-controller (and request for an existing file is ignored) before your redirect is triggered - so no redirect occurs.

If this is the case then you need to move your rule to the top of the file, *before* any existing rewrites.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/(.*)$
> RewriteRule ^(.*) https://newdomain.com/folder/%1 [R=301,NC]
> ```

However, your existing rule is not quite correct. Importantly, you are missing the `L` flag on the `RewriteRule` directive and the preceding `RewriteCond` directive is not required. For example, try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/.* https://newdomain.com/$0 [NC,R=301,L]
```

This does assume your `.htaccess` file is located in the document root of the site.

**Alternatively**, you create an additional `.htaccess` file inside the `/folder` with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ https://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full URL-path of the request (including the slash prefix).

By default, the mod_rewrite directives in the `/folder/.htaccess` file will completely override any directives in the parent (root) `.htaccess` file (the mod_rewrite directives in the parent are not even processed).